# Trying to compile basic program in Agda

Tags: agda

I've got agda running on my machiene but I'm having difficulty running a basic example from the 'learn you an agda' tutorial

the web page is here: http://learnyouanagda.liamoc.net/pages/peano.html

I've put together the code from the tutorial

```
module peano where

data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ

_+_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ 
zero + zero = zero
zero + n    = n
(suc n) + n′ = suc (n + n′)
```

but when I try 'loading' the file, in preperation for compiling it throws the following error:

```
/home/adjam/Desktop/first_program.agda:3,8-13
The name of the top level module does not match the file name. The
module peano should be defined in one of the following files:
  /home/adjam/Desktop/peano.agda
  /home/adjam/Desktop/peano.lagda
  /usr/share/agda-stdlib/peano.agda
```

How do I get this code to compile and run? I don't know how to add a library like 'peano'. I'm an agda beginner and a really clear walk through with code examples would be much appreciated.

If I just do

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ
```

The file compiles

If I just skip the peano library like this

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ


_+_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ 
zero + zero = zero
zero + n    = n
(suc n) + n′ = suc (n + n′)
```

then I get the error

```
/home/adjam/Desktop/first_program.agda:10,1-1
/home/adjam/Desktop/first_program.agda:10,1: Parse error
_+_<ERROR>
 : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ 
zero + zero = ze...
```

How do I fix this? Do I need peano to make this code compile? If so how do I do that?

Comment: I found that I can compile the code as long as its in a folder with lots of agda libraries in it called 'common'

Answer (score 1):

To fix your first error, you need to carefully read the error message:

> The name of the top level module does not match the file name.

Your file is called `first_program.agda` and not `peano.agda` hence the error. You need to either rename the file or call the toplevel module `first_program`.

Once the module header is removed, I don't get your second error: the file parses just fine for me.